# Limit of unique permissions per site collection

Tags: 2013, permissions, site-collection, security-trimming

How many items/documents/folders with unique permissions can you have per site collection?

I am aware of the boundaries of 5,000 scopes per list/library and 5,000 members per scope.

I assume it is acceptable to use a SharePoint site as a container for each 5,000 items/document with unique permissions (as Issue 2 in this article indicates: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169566.aspx). Now, 250,000 sites are supported per site-collection - does this mean you can build structures that support 5,000 x 250,000 items/documents/folders with unique permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to check this article: http://www.trustsharepoint.com/2013/03/updated-sharepoint-2013-software.html. 5,000 is the limit at which performance starts to suffer but you can increase beyond that. Microsoft has updated the threshold to 50,000 scopes per list/library.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that article but I do not feel that it answers my question. Yes, you can have up to 50,000 unique items per list, but how can you scale that approach and what is the ultimate limit? BTW increasing the limit beyond 5,000 per list has a performance price as additional round trips to the SQL database are needed.

Comment: If you're concerned about reaching the 5,000 limit, only other approach that comes to mind is grouping similar items in folders and giving the folder unique permissions instead of items which will reduce the number of scopes.